# Load cells in Wheatstone bridge to produce logic signal

Tags: load, bridge

The goal is to use 4 units of 50kg load cells in Wheatstone bridge to act as a load detector. It should output a logic 0 or 1 if the load is greater than a threshold value. A MCU will read the states of 100 load detectors through a series of PISO shift register. Potentiometers will be used to adjust threshold level and they have to be placed near the MCU which is 5-10 meters away from the load detectors.

I have trouble determining a circuit to read the differential voltage signals from the bridge. A signal amplifier IC and a comparator IC might be sufficient. But is there other approach?

[image]

Edit: The default weight around 2kg. The threshold value varies from 5kg to 20kg.

Comment: how stable (grams/hour drift) must the "thresholding" be?

Comment: The default load is around 2kg. The threshold is around 5kg-20kg.

Comment: Well, the load cells and the AFE is quite expensive and easily broken if you never had experience with load cells before - they need also a mechanical protection stop. An the other hand, if only presence is to be evaluated, there are plenty of mechanical levers, scales that can  be used to detect weight with use of microswitch or inductive proximity sensor. This is how it is made in food processing machines, like poultry overhead conveyor,..etc They don't waste money for expensive devices if not needed.

Comment: Do your signal processing after the multiplexer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an indirect current feedback instrumentation amplifier MAX or Analog Devices,...then subtract tare or threshold setpoint value. Make the REF input voltage such that you will have some well defined voltage in middle of supply voltage, so you can use some comparator with in-built reference voltage.

[image]

Note that AD needs an opamp buffer for REF voltage, while MAX has a built in buffer.

[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f33Z6N.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Let we have a load cell with 2mV/V and you supply the cell with 5V, so it would output 10mV at full span, 10mV/50kg = 0.2mV/kg. You want to have an adjustment of 5-20kg, so delta mass is 15kg and delta V is 3mV. Let we amplify this with gain of 1000 and we get voltage swing of 3V.

$$V_{out}=G(V_+-V_-)+V_{REF}$$
$$V_{out}=-200\dfrac{mV}{kg}\cdot m +V_{REF}$$
$$V_{out}[20kg]=-4V +V_{REF}$$
$$V_{out}[5kg]=-1.0V +V_{REF}$$
$$m>20kg: V_{REF}-4V < 0.4V ; V_{REF} = 4.4V$$
$$m>5kg: V_{REF}-1.0V < 0.4V ; V_{REF} = 1.4V$$
You invert the cell output, so that signal subtracts from V_ref.